# A bilateral weighted shift $T$ with $\sigma(T) =$ unit circle

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I am looking for an example of a bilateral weighted shift $T\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})) $ with $\sigma(T) = \mathbb{T}$, which is the  unit circle.

NOTE: what I'm looking for a bilateral weighted shift such that $Te_n=t_ne_{n+1}$ with $t_n$ a non-constant.

I know that a bilateral shift $S$ with $Se_n=e_{n+1}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$,  has spectrum $\sigma(S)=\mathbb{T}$.

So I started trying out things.

Here are some ideas:

Let $T$ be defined by $Te_n =t_ne_{n+1}$, where

$ t_n= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{1+n},& \text{if } n\geq 0\\
    \frac{1}{1-n},              & \text{if } n <0
\end{cases}
$

First we know that the spectrum is always closed.

But I'm not sure how to find out if the spectrum of this is $\mathbb{T}$.

To show $\sigma(T) \subset \mathbb{T}$, some facts that might be needed are:

The spectrum is always closed.

Could someone please let me know if my example works?

If it does, why $\sigma(T) = \mathbb{T}$?

If not, could I get some suggestions on the other possible weighted shifts? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. You already have $S$ with spectrum $\mathbb T$.

Comment: I am looking for a a weighted shift  $T$ with $t_n \ne 1$

Comment: Since when $t_n=1$, we have $\sigma(T)= \mathbb{T}$, that why I I'm trying to use weights $t_n$ that are very close to $1$.

Comment: Take $iS$, then.

Comment: But if $t_n=i$, we don't have $t_n \in \ell^\infty (\mathbb{Z})$ anymore..do we?

Comment: Why not? $ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: Oh right... Sorry I just confused myself earlier. I'm looking for a $t_n$ that is non-constant. I'm so sorry for the confusion......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any bilateral shift with weights in $\mathbb T$ will have spectrum $\mathbb T$, so you can choose $t_n$ to be whatever you want, as long as $|t_n|=1$.

This is because if you define $Ve_n=\lambda^ne_n$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb T$, then
$$
VTe_n=t_nVe_{n+1}=t_n\lambda^{n+1}e_{n+1},\qquad\qquad TVe_n=\lambda^nTe_n=t_n\lambda^ne_n. 
$$
So $TV=\lambda VT$. As $V$ is a unitary, $V^*TV=\lambda T$. Then
$$
\sigma(T)=\sigma(V^*TV)=\lambda\sigma(T). 
$$
That is, $\sigma(T)$ is invariant for rotation, as we can do this for any $\lambda\in\mathbb T$. So $\sigma(T)=\mathbb T$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Why do we have $T= V^*TV$?

Comment: We don't. $ \ $

Comment: Then how did you get $\sigma(T) = \sigma(V^*TV)$?

Comment: Using the definition of the spectrum. $V^*TV-\lambda I=V^*(T-\lambda I)V$, so $V^*TV-\lambda I$ is invertible precisely when $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.